Single Jacoco code coverage report for multi-module project
I have multi-module android gradle project. I have implemented Jacoco into my project which will generate code coverage report for each and every module.
The problem is all module reports are generated separately inside build directory of each module.
I want to generate Single report for my whole project. I have tried using jacoco-report-aggregation but no luck. Also tried manual way to combine report but didn't get succeeded.
Q. How can I generate single code coverage report for my multi-module project? if any working example is there it will be huge help.
